# branchless bitwise operation

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitmask

I'm looking for a branchless bitwise operation that can determine with a given mask :

> Mask : 0xFF0000 Value : 0xAA0000 return : true
>
> Mask : 0xFF0000 Value : 0xAA00AA return : false
>
> Mask : 0xFF00FF Value : 0xBB00AA return : true
>
> Mask : 0xFF00FF Value : 0x0000AA return : false
>
> Mask : 0xFF00FF Value : 0xAA0000 return : false
>
> Mask : 0xFF00FF Value : 0x0A00AA return : true

That's is : it must returns true if :

- the mask has a byte set to 0, the value must have the same byte to 0.
- the mask has a byte set to > 0, the value must have the same byte
  different of 0.

Edit :

0xFFFF00 and 0x00AA00 should not match.
If the mask has a byte > 0, the value must have the same byte > 0.

That's is : If the mask has this pattern [XX][00][XX], the value must have the same. Where XX can be from 01 to FF in the value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that we're only dealing with the low-order three bytes, as per the question.

A simple solution (17 operations):

```
((mask & 0x0000FF) == 0) == ((value & 0x0000FF) == 0) &&
((mask & 0x00FF00) == 0) == ((value & 0x00FF00) == 0) &&
((mask & 0xFF0000) == 0) == ((value & 0xFF0000) == 0)
```

A better solution (9 operations):

```
(((mask & 0x7F7F7F) + 0x7F7F7F | mask) & 0x808080) ==
(((value & 0x7F7F7F) + 0x7F7F7F | value) & 0x808080)
```

A third solution (9 operations):

```
!((((mask & 0x7F7F7F) + 0x7F7F7F | mask) ^
((value & 0x7F7F7F) + 0x7F7F7F | value)) & 0x808080)
```

The third solution can be reduced to 8 operations by dropping the `!` surrounding the entire expression if your code is prepared to handle zero as pass and non-zero as fail.